# Weird button behaviour in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am making todo list with JS and jQuery. And I have come across a problem where, I am appending the button into  the HTML with JS (code below). And the problem is that the button is appended with class to it. The class is set to just give the button width, height ,bacground-color, color, border, and border-radius.

The problem apears when I add the border-radius property to the button. The border becomes round and thas okay, but on the places where border shinked it is now white (image below).

But if I just put a button element in HTML code it works normaly. This is happening only when I am appending the button.

Does anyone knows why is this happening, and how can I fix this.

```
**//Everything is happening on a button click**


**//Here is the css class**

.btn{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: var(--boja1);
    color: var(--boja4);
    border: 2px solid var(--boja4);
    border-radius: 20px;
}

**//Here I am appending a div element to html**

var boxx=document.createElement("div");
boxx.innerHTML=`<div class="box" id="box"></div>`;

txt1.before(boxx);

**//Here I am apending not important P thag to the div eleement**

var element=document.createElement("p");
element.innerHTML=`<p class="newItem" id="new`+ne+`" >`+text+`</p>`;

$("#box").append(element);

**//And here I am appending the button that is causing me the problem  to the P thag above**

var bt=document.createElement("button");
bt.innerHTML=`<button class="btn" id=""> &#x2715</button>`


$(`#new`+ne+``).append(bt);
```

[This is how the button looks before adding the border-radius property in css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTW79.png)

[ANd this is how it looks after I add it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqG7O.png)

```
//HTML CODE

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="td.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" 
    integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="mDiv">

        <p class="naslov" id="naslov">ToDo List  </p>

        <div class="mmDiv" id="mmDiv">
            <input type="text" id="txt1" class="txt1">
            <button class="button1" id="button1"> Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button id="delete" class="delete">Delete</button>
    <button> <button class="btn">dwad</button> </button>
    
    


    <script src="td.js"></script>
</body>
</html>





//CSS CODE

*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    outline: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }
body{
     /* background: linear-gradient(45deg, var(--boja3) 10%, var(--gradient2) ) ; 
     --boja4: rgb(20,8,42);
    --boja1: rgb(252,245,219); 

     --boja3: rgb(212,149,143);
    --gradient2: rgb(189,156,173);  */

    background-color: var(--boja3);
    --boja1: #534859;
    --boja2: #FBF0E8;

    --boja3: #FBD0D0;
    --boja4: #F9688D;
    


    margin: 0.1px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.n{
    display:none;
}

.mDiv{
    width: 600px;
    height: 820px;
    background-color: var(--boja1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 35%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    /* text-align: center; */
}
.naslov{
    font-size: 40px;
    color: var(--boja4);
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 30px var(--boja4);
}
.txt1{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    outline: 2px solid var(--boja4);
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 130px;
    background-color: var(--boja1);
    color: var(--boja4);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px var(--boja4);
}
/* .txt1:focus{
    background-color: var(--boja4);
    color: var(--boja1);
} */
.button1{
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: var(--boja1);
    color: var(--boja4);
    outline: 2px solid var(--boja4);
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px var(--boja4);
}
.button1:hover{
    background-color: var(--boja4);
    color: var(--boja1);
    transform: scale(110%);
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px var(--boja4);

}
.button1:active{
    transform: scale(80%);
}
.newItem{
    color: var(--boja4);
    font-size: 40px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px var(--boja4);
    background-color: var(--boja1);
    /* margin-left: -240px;
    margin-top: 100px; */
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    z-index: 20;
    /* border-radius: 20px; */
    /* background-color: transparent; */
}
/* .newItem::before{
    content: '';
    background-color: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid var(--boja4);

} */
.mmDiv{
    outline:2px solid var(--boja4);
    width: 550px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px var(--boja4);
    margin-top: 20px;
    
}
.box{
   
    width: 550px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-left: -6px;
    
}
.linija{
    outline: 1px solid var(--boja4);
    width:100%;
    height: 0px;
}
.delete{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: var(--boja1);
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: var(--boja1);
    color: var(--boja4);
    outline: 2px solid var(--boja4);
    position: absolute;
    top: 7%;
    left: 61.6%;   
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px var(--boja4);
}
.delete:hover{
    background-color: var(--boja4);
    color: var(--boja1);
    transform: scale(110%);
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px var(--boja4);
}
.delete:active{
    transform: scale(80%);
}
.radio{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -32px;
    margin-left: -26px;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: 999999;

}
.radio:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.cd{
    margin-top: -34px;
    margin-left: -28px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid var(--boja4);
    background-color: var(--boja1);
}
.cm{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -27px;
    margin-left: -24px;
    color: var(--boja1);
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: none;
    z-index: 99;
}
.btn{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: var(--boja1);
    color: var(--boja4);
    border: 2px solid var(--boja4);
    border-radius: 20px;
}

//JS CODE

let button1=$("#button1");
let txt1=$("#txt1");
let a=$("#r1");
let text;

let br=0;

let mmDiv=$("#mmDiv");
let x;

let box=$("#box");
let alert=document.createElement("p");
alert.innerHTML=`<p class="alert">You can have up to 15 points on the list!</p>`;

let i=0;
let r=0;
let cd1=0;
let cm1=0;
let ne=0;

function dodaj(){
    txt1.on('input',()=>{
        txt1.css("color","var(--boja1)");
        console.log(x);
        if(x=="Eneter something! "){
            txt1.val("");
            x=" ";
        }
    });

    txt1.focus(()=>{
        if(txt1.val()=="Eneter something! "){
            
            txt1.val("");
            return;
        }
        else{
            txt1.css("color","var(--boja1)");
        }
    });
    if(txt1.val()=="Eneter something! "){
        
        return;
    }
    if(txt1.val()==""){
        txt1.val("Eneter something! ");
        x=txt1.val();
        txt1.css("color","red");
        return;
    }

   
        if(br!=15)
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
                var boxx=document.createElement("div");
                boxx.innerHTML=`<div class="box" id="box"></div>`;
                i=1
            }


            br++;

            txt1.before(boxx);
            console.log("lmao");


            txt1.css("margin-top"," 10px");


            text=txt1.val();

            ne++;
            var element=document.createElement("p");
            element.innerHTML=`<p class="newItem" id="new`+ne+`" >`+text+`</p>`;
            
            var linija=document.createElement("div");
            linija.innerHTML=`<div class="linija"></div>`;

            r++;
            cd1++;
            cm1++;
            
            var del=document.createElement("p");
            del.innerHTML=`<input type="checkbox" class="radio" id="r`+r+`">`

            var cd=document.createElement('p');
            cd.innerHTML=`<p class="cd" id="cd`+cd1+`"></p>`;

            var cm=document.createElement("p");
            cm.innerHTML=`<p class="cm" id="cm`+cm1+`">&#10004</p>`

            var bt=document.createElement("button");
            bt.innerHTML=`<button class="btn" id=""> &#x2715</button>`

            $("#box").append(element);
            $("#box").append(linija);
            $(`#new`+ne+``).append(del);
            $(`#new`+ne+``).append(cd);
            $(`#new`+ne+``).append(cm);
            // $(`#new${ne}`).style.borderRadius("20px");
            $(`#new${ne}`).append(bt);
            // $(`#new`+ne+``).append(bt);
        
            txt1.val("");
            
            console.log(text);
        }
        if(br==15){
            
            txt1.before(alert);
            txt1.css("display","none");
            button1.css("display","none");
            $(".alert").css("color","red");
        }
}
a=$("#r1");
button1.click(()=>{
    dodaj();
});
document.addEventListener("keydown",(dugme)=>{
    if(dugme.key=="Enter")
    {
        dodaj();
    }
});

document.addEventListener("keydown",(dugme)=>{
    if(dugme.key=="/")
    {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            txt1.focus();
        },100);
    }
})

let del=$("#delete");
del.click(()=>{
    $("#box").remove();
    br=0;
    i=0;
    $(".alert").remove();
    txt1.css("display","inline-block");
    button1.css("display","inline-block");
    txt1.val("");
});

txt1.focus(()=>{
    txt1.css("color","var(--boja1)");
    txt1.css("background-color","var(--boja4)");
});

txt1.blur(()=>{
    txt1.css("color","var(--boja4)");
    txt1.css("background-color","var(--boja1)");
});

// $("#cd").css("background-color","var(--boja4)");
// $(`#txt1`).css("background-color","var(--boja4)");
let nb1541=0;
$("body").on("click", `#r1`, () => {
    
    if(nb1541==0){
        $(`#cd1`).css("background-color", "var(--boja4)");
        nb1541=1;
        console.log("Prvi: "+nb1541);
        return;
    }
    if(nb1541==1){
        $(`#cd1`).css("background-color", "var(--boja1)");   
        console.log("Drugi: "+nb1541);
        nb1541=0;
        return;
    }
});
let nb1542=0;
$("body").on("click", `#r2`, () => {
    
    if(nb1542==0){
        $(`#cd2`).css("background-color", "var(--boja4)");
        nb1542=1;
        console.log("Prvi: "+nb1542);
        return;
    }
    if(nb1542==1){
        $(`#cd2`).css("background-color", "var(--boja1)");   
        console.log("Drugi: "+nb1542);
        nb1542=0;
        return;
    }
});
let nb1543=0;
$("body").on("click", `#r3`, () => {
    
    if(nb1543==0){
        $(`#cd3`).css("background-color", "var(--boja4)");
        nb1543=1;
        console.log("Prvi: "+nb1543);
        return;
    }
    if(nb1543==1){
        $(`#cd3`).css("background-color", "var(--boja1)");   
        console.log("Drugi: "+nb1543);
        nb1543=0;
        return;
    }
});

let nb154=0;
$("body").on("click", `#r4`, () => {
    
    if(nb154==0){
        $(`#cd4`).css("background-color", "var(--boja4)");
        nb154=1;
        console.log("Prvi: "+nb154);
        return;
    }
    if(nb154==1){
        $(`#cd4`).css("background-color", "var(--boja1)");   
        console.log("Drugi: "+nb154);
        nb154=0;
        return;
    }
});

let nb155=0;
$("body").on("click", `#r5`, () => {
    
    if(nb155==0){
        $(`#cd5`).css("background-color", "var(--boja4)");
        nb155=1;
        console.log("Prvi: "+nb155);
        return;
    }
    if(nb155==1){
        $(`#cd5`).css("background-color", "var(--boja1)");   
        console.log("Drugi: "+nb155);
        nb155=0;
        return;
    }
});
let nb156=0;
$("body").on("click", `#r6`, () => {
    
    if(nb156==0){
        $(`#cd6`).css("background-color", "var(--boja4)");
        nb156=1;
        console.log("Prvi: "+nb156);
        return;
    }
    if(nb156==1){
        $(`#cd6`).css("background-color", "var(--boja1)");   
        console.log("Drugi: "+nb156);
        nb156=0;
        return;
    }
});
let nb157=0;
$("body").on("click", `#r7`, () => {
    
    if(nb157==0){
        $(`#cd7`).css("background-color", "var(--boja4)");
        nb157=1;
        console.log("Prvi: "+nb157);
        return;
    }
    if(nb157==1){
        $(`#cd7`).css("background-color", "var(--boja1)");   
        console.log("Drugi: "+nb157);
        nb157=0;
        return;
    }
});
let nb158=0;
$("body").on("click", `#r8`, () => {
    
    if(nb158==0){
        $(`#cd8`).css("background-color", "var(--boja4)");
        nb158=1;
        console.log("Prvi: "+nb158);
        return;
    }
    if(nb158==1){
        $(`#cd8`).css("background-color", "var(--boja1)");   
        console.log("Drugi: "+nb158);
        nb158=0;
        return;
    }
});
let nb159=0;
$("body").on("click", `#r9`, () => {
    
    if(nb159==0){
        $(`#cd9`).css("background-color", "var(--boja4)");
        nb159=1;
        console.log("Prvi: "+nb159);
        return;
    }
    if(nb159==1){
        $(`#cd9`).css("background-color", "var(--boja1)");   
        console.log("Drugi: "+nb159);
        nb159=0;
        return;
    }
});
let nb1510=0;
$("body").on("click", `#r10`, () => {
    
    if(nb1510==0){
        $(`#cd10`).css("background-color", "var(--boja4)");
        nb1510=1;
        console.log("Prvi: "+nb1510);
        return;
    }
    if(nb1510==1){
        $(`#cd10`).css("background-color", "var(--boja1)");   
        console.log("Drugi: "+nb1510);
        nb1510=0;
        return;
    }
});
let nb1511=0;
$("body").on("click", `#r11`, () => {
    
    if(nb1511==0){
        $(`#cd11`).css("background-color", "var(--boja4)");
        nb1511=1;
        console.log("Prvi: "+nb1511);
        return;
    }
    if(nb1511==1){
        $(`#cd11`).css("background-color", "var(--boja1)");   
        console.log("Drugi: "+nb1511);
        nb1511=0;
        return;
    }
});
let nb1512=0;
$("body").on("click", `#r12`, () => {
    
    if(nb1512==0){
        $(`#cd12`).css("background-color", "var(--boja4)");
        nb1512=1;
        console.log("Prvi: "+nb1512);
        return;
    }
    if(nb1512==1){
        $(`#cd12`).css("background-color", "var(--boja1)");   
        console.log("Drugi: "+nb1512);
        nb1512=0;
        return;
    }
});
let nb1513=0;
$("body").on("click", `#r13`, () => {
    
    if(nb1513==0){
        $(`#cd13`).css("background-color", "var(--boja4)");
        nb1513=1;
        console.log("Prvi: "+nb1513);
        return;
    }
    if(nb1513==1){
        $(`#cd13`).css("background-color", "var(--boja1)");   
        console.log("Drugi: "+nb1513);
        nb1513=0;
        return;
    }
});
let nb1514=0;
$("body").on("click", `#r14`, () => {
    
    if(nb1514==0){
        $(`#cd14`).css("background-color", "var(--boja4)");
        nb1514=1;
        console.log("Prvi: "+nb1514);
        return;
    }
    if(nb1514==1){
        $(`#cd14`).css("background-color", "var(--boja1)");   
        console.log("Drugi: "+nb1514);
        nb1514=0;
        return;
    }
});
let nb15=0;
$("body").on("click", `#r15`, () => {
    
    if(nb15==0){
        $(`#cd15`).css("background-color", "var(--boja4)");
        nb15=1;
        console.log("Prvi: "+nb15);
        return;
    }
    if(nb15==1){
        $(`#cd15`).css("background-color", "var(--boja1)");   
        console.log("Drugi: "+nb15);
        nb15=0;
        return;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line,

```
var bt=document.createElement("button");
bt.innerHTML=`<button class="btn" id="">`;
```

You already create a `button` element, Again adding `<button>` as HTML content. This causes **nested button** situation like `<button><button class="btn" id=""/></button>`.

All you have to do is:

```js
var bt=document.createElement("button");
bt.classList.add("btn");
bt.innerHTML="&#x2715";
```

Comment: Ohhh, thanks mann.
You saved me a lot of trouble, cause I was alsou worrying about the nesting thigs where I had doubled the thags.
Thank you very much again <3

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem was that my button was appending in the HTML inside the other button thag
Image of the web tools
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMm9m.png

And I fixed this problem, by just shangeing the thag from button to p thag in JS
And keeping the `innerHTML` value as button

```
// OLD
var bt = document.createElement("button");
bt.innerHTML=`<button class="btn" id=""> &#x2715</button>`
// NEW
var bt = document.createElement("p");
bt.innerHTML=`<button class="btn" id=""> &#x2715</button>`
```

Comment: you don't need another`p`, Look at my answer.